# The on-hover hint of the Delete button

Tags: feature-request, delete

I have recently noticed that the on-hover hint of the Delete button (at the bottom of posts) is not informative for post owners.

The hint states "vote to delete" and does not make any sense, since, as an owner, you will immediately delete it.

Further, as a post owner, I could not find anywhere in the site that instructions indicating that I could undelete the post later (by doing some hack or not). It could be extremely useful for people like me that edit a lot, for example, to remove the post temporarily.

The hack is to create a chat from the question BEFORE one deletes it, and leave the chat opened until you finish your edits (of course, may be other legitimate ways to keep the deleted post until you have done your work).

So I am suggesting an update to the hint. Instead of "vote to delete this post" and "vote to undelete this post", post owners should see something like:

> "Delete this post. You must hack the site to be able to undelete it later".

and

> " Undelete this post. Congratulations, you have hacked the site!"

Of course I am kidding. We should discuss the hints.

Comment: You should be able to see an "undelete" option on a post that you have permissions to undelete (or vote to undelete). Are you sure there is not one?

Comment: There is an undelete option, indeed. But I did not say that there was not.

Comment: *Further, I could not find anywhere in the site that, as a post owner, I could undelete the post* <-- I read that to understand you could not, as a post owner, find it.....

Comment: Relevant [meta.se] question: [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/148099)

Comment: Sorry @rolfl, language issues I think.

Answer (score 3):

Although the hover is a bit misleading indeed, the confirmation box leaves no room for misinterpretation:

[image: Delete this post?]

No voting, no ambiguity, just three words.

I don't want to go into UX here, but I think the current situation is quite safe for beginners. Those who already know what they're doing aren't interested in the hover anyway.

Comment: The confirmation box was not under analysis. The on hover hint **is not** informative. It should be.

Comment: If you care about details, no conflicting information should be ok for you.